# Chrome on android return everytime 229 for keyCode

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome

I have this piece of code :

```
...
@HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
onKeyDown(evt: KeyboardEvent) {
    console.log('KeyCode : ' + evt.keyCode);
    console.log('Which : ' + evt.which);
    ....
}
```

For ios checked all browsers --> working just fine

For android, is working on firefox, but on chrome I have `229` for `evt.keyCode` && `evt.which`, doesn't matter which key is pressed.

Have an idea about this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

`evt.keyCode` is deprecated, instead use [evt.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) which returns a `String` description of the key.

Nevertheless, it won't work on Chrome Android anyway, being [a well known bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=809107) of the Chromium project.

It should work on Firefox Android.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like `keyCode` is deprecated, and is still supported in some browsers for legacy reasons:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

Instead, it is recommended to use `evt.code`.

> You should avoid using this if possible; it's been deprecated for some time. Instead, you should use KeyboardEvent.code, if it's implemented. Unfortunately, some browsers still don't have it, so you'll have to be careful to make sure you use one which is supported on all target browsers.

Judging by [the supported browsers table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode#browser_compatibility) for the feature, you should be fine using `key`.

Comment: is not working, `evt.code` return empty on android, chrome browser

Comment: Strange. Are you adding the listener to the correct DOM element? For me (desktop Firefox, so might be different!) It works if I attach the listener to `window` like so: `window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => console.log(e.code));`